# In React Native, is there a way to send NSNotifications without using Native Modules?

Tags: react-native

I'm looking for ways of writing simple UI handler code in Objective-C that doesn't require a call-back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such Module. You can make your own one. It's very simple.

**Code:**

```
//  NotificationManager.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface NotificationManager : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end

//  NotificationManager.m
#import "NotificationManager.h"

@implementation NotificationManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(postNotification:(NSString *)name) {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:name object:nil userInfo:nil];
}

@end
```

Now you can simple post notification from JavaScript

```
var NotificationManager = require('react-native').NativeModules.NotificationManager;
NotificationManager.postNotification("TestEvent")
```

Comment: Awesome — perhaps we can host this as a react.part!

Comment: yes or make a Pull Request to add it as a part of React Native