# Equivalent of NSNotificationCenter for React Native?

Tags: react-native

Been searching for a while to see if there's anything built-in or any 3rd party modules for adding NSNotificationCenter style functionality to a react-native app.

Specifically, I want modules to "listen" for certain notification types, and I will be able to "broadcast" events from other parts of the app (from within javascript).

The closest thing I've found is this from 3 days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32004456/798533, but it only supports sending NSNotificationCenter events, not listening.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I figured out an acceptable solution. Here's what I ended up doing in case anybody has the same question:

I installed the npm package [backbone-events-standalone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/backbone-events-standalone), which is just the extracted events code from Backbone.js.

In the main entry point for my app (`index.ios.js`), I included the following code by the imports:

```
var BackboneEvents = require('backbone-events-standalone');
// global event bus
window.EventBus = BackboneEvents.mixin({});
```

Inside any component's `componentDidMount`, you can now add event listeners, like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.EventBus.on('yourEventName', this.yourEventHandlerFunc);
}
```

And you can fire events thusly:

```
window.EventBus.trigger('yourEventName', 'optional event info');
```

This could also easily be combined with NSNotificationCenter events using something like the solution linked in the original question.

If you're removing components, it would be wise to also remove the event listeners, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Can I use this for multiple components listening on same event in their componentDidMount()

Comment: @meteors sure, don't see why not

Comment: I used it. But . The class in which its being used. that triggered method doesn't recognise any method or property of that class.

Comment: @powers can you say, How to remove trigger. because it called multiple time.

Comment: @KiritModi You can remove listeners with the `.off` method: `window.EventBus.off('yourEventName', this.yourEventHandlerFunc);` - Docs: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off

Comment: @mmh02 Thanks, I will try.

Comment: it's working when app killed or in background in android ??